# SQL need to compare rows count values

Tags: sql, count, dbvisualizer

I have a query that returns the ID, Name and count of the number of times an ID has been entered to the table.

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    NAME,
    COUNT(*) count
FROM 
    TABLE
GROUP BY
    NAME, ID, CASE_DETAIL_ID
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1;
```

This returns the following data:

| ID | NAME | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | HAT | 10 |
| 123 | UMBRELLA | 10 |
| 123 | TOWEL | 10 |
| 123 | WATER | 8 |
| 555 | HAT | 3 |
| 555 | UMBRELLA | 10 |
| 555 | TOWEL | 10 |
| 555 | WATER | 10 |
| 322 | UMBRELLA | 5 |
| 322 | TOWEL | 20 |
| 322 | WATER | 20 |

I want to be able to query the row with a count of less than what the other rows with the same ID have. How can I do this? So that the end result is:

| ID | NAME | COUNT | FULL COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | WATER | 8 | 10 |
| 555 | HAT | 3 | 10 |
| 322 | UMBRELLA | 5 | 20 |

There are multiple IDs that we store and I only want the rows/names that have a count less than the rows with the same IDs have.

I have also tried -

```
WITH x AS
        (SELECT ID, NAME, COUNT(*) count
        FROM FRT.CASE_DETAIL_HISTORY
        GROUP BY
        NAME,
        ID,
        CASE_DETAIL_ID)
SELECT x.ID, t.NAME, X.COUNT, MIN(x.count)
FROM x
JOIN FRT.CASE_DETAIL_HISTORY t
on t.ID= x.ID
GROUP BY x.ID, t.ID, X.COUNT
```

However, this doesnt give me what I am looking for. I only want rows returned if the name's count doesnt match the 'mode' count of the ID.
I also have tried the below but keep facing errors:

```
WITH COUNT_OF_ROWS AS 
    (SELECT ID, NAME, COUNT(*) count
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY NAME, ID, CASE_DETAIL_ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1),
    
MINIMUM AS
    (SELECT COUNT_OF_ROWS.ID, COUNT_OF_ROWS.NAME, 
MIN(COUNT_OF_ROWS.COUNT) MINI
    FROM COUNT_OF_ROWS
    JOIN TABLE CD on CD.ID = COUNT_OF_ROWS.ID
    GROUP BY COUNT_OF_ROWS.ID, COUNT_OF_ROWS.NAME
)
     
select distinct COUNT_OF_ROWS.*, MINIMUM.MINI
from minimum, count_of_rows
where minimum.mini != count_of_rows.count;
```

Comment: can you share the schema and sample values of your `TABLE` table?

Comment: Hi - Are you unable to see the table or just need more examples?

Comment: I only see the output of your first query and the output you need, but can't see the input table you called `TABLE` in your query. @AmachineR I'm asking you because maybe you can do everything with one efficient query instead of doing multiple queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some sample data would help but you can use a CTE, and `select` the lowest using `min()` something like this:

```sql
WITH x AS(
    SELECT t.id, t.nametext, COUNT(*) as count
    FROM table t
    GROUP BY id, t.nametext, CASE_DETAIL_ID
), y as(
    SELECT x.id, MIN(x.[COUNT]) as mincount
    FROM x
    GROUP BY x.id
)
select y.id, x.nametext, y.mincount
from y
join x
on x.[COUNT] = y.mincount
and x.id = y.id
```

Or it can be done using `top 1` and `order by` like this:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 id, name, COUNT(*) as count
FROM TABLE
WHERE ID = 123
GROUP BY NAME, ID, CASE_DETAIL_ID
ORDER BY count DESC
```

But bare in mind that as this would `select` only the first row, this would only work with the `where` clause because it would always only return 1 row.

While if you use the CTE option it would work also if you want per id, without `where id = 123`.

Comment: Would I be able to add the full count as well? I updated the tables above. For some reason using the CTE query- when I include x.count in the select returns the same values for both

Comment: `WITH COUNT_OF_ROWS AS 
        (SELECT ID, NAME, COUNT(*) count
        FROM TABLE
        GROUP BY NAME, ID, CASE_DETAIL_ID
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1),
        
MINIMUM AS
        (SELECT COUNT_OF_ROWS.ID, COUNT_OF_ROWS.NAME, MIN(COUNT_OF_ROWS.COUNT) MINI
        FROM COUNT_OF_ROWS
        JOIN TABLE CD on CD.ID = COUNT_OF_ROWS.ID
        GROUP BY COUNT_OF_ROWS.CASE_ID, COUNT_OF_ROWS.NAME
)
        
select distinct COUNT_OF_ROWS.*, MINIMUM.MINI
from minimum, count_of_rows
where minimum.mini != count_of_rows.count;`